# Send an email on Sails.JS using Mailgun?

Tags: sails.js, mailgun

I'm trying to send an email on Sails.JS but I don't know how to do it. I saw a lot of tutorials but none of the tutorials helped me to send an email. I can send an email with the console using `curl`.

I tried to configure Mailgun but I don't have a Domain. I'm trying to do it free and I'm also very new on Mailgun and Sails.JS. My purpose is to send an email on Sails.JS, but I don't know how.

Comment: You actually don't need a domain on mailgun. 
You can also use a sandbox domain of mail itself.  But then you can only send mails to whitelisted people.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps below to send email from sailsjs using mailgun

Install mailgun module

> npm install mailgun-js --save

Create custom variables in config/custom.js file

> mailgunDomain: 'yourmailgundomain',
>
> mailgunSecret: 'yourmailgunkey',
>
> mailgunFrom:'yourmailgunfrommail',

Create a helper

> sails generate helper send-single-email

```
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: sails.config.custom.mailgunSecret, domain: sails.config.custom.mailgunDomain});
module.exports = {


friendlyName: 'Send single email',


description: '',


inputs: {
options:{
  type:'json'
 }
},


exits: {

},


fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

mailgun.messages().send(inputs.options, function (error, body) {
  if(error){
    return exits.error(error)
  }

  // All done.
return exits.success(body);


});

}


};
```

Call your helper from any controller

```
await sails.helpers.mail.sendSingleEmail({
    to:'destination@email.com',
    from:sails.config.custom.mailgunFrom,
    subject:'Subject',
    text:'Your message'
  })
```

Comment: hello, I did all you said and when i run and wants to send email get this error:
error: Error: Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings.
what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

To use Mailgun, you'll need to sign up for an account. (While this *is* a paid service at higher usage levels, you should be able to use Mailgun as much as you need to in development without having to provide any credit card information.)

After you've created an account, you'll need to add your Mailgun domain and API secret to your custom config. (In development, this will be either in `config/custom.js`, or in a `local.js` file you add to your `config/` folder. For your staging or production deployment, you'll want to set these using system environment variables -- aka "config variables" in Heroku.)

If you already own a domain for your app, you can follow Mailgun's instructions for configuring a sending domain.

Otherwise, to send emails from this app *without* configuring a sending domain, you can use the sandbox domain & test API secret that comes with your Mailgun account. Just be sure to configure the authorized recipents for your sandbox domain first, or there will be errors from the endpoints that attempt to send emails.

~~Copied from Sails.js FAQ page when downloading a new app

Comment: I configured the mailgun creds in the config file and also changed the verifyEmail to true but no mails are being sent, how do I solve this